# Selenium Select Input Box that Changes Name Every Session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access a search text box inside of our company's ERP system using `Selenium`.  The screenshot shows the text box and the `Xpath` of the element.

This is a little tricky, because that `Menu Search` pop-up isn't really a pop-up.  It somehow shows up when a user types `Control + M`.

By installing `ChroPath` and testing I've found the text-box always starts with the following string:

```
txtMenuSearch_Namespace_
```

I've tried to imitate what's described [here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298667/finding-webelement-with-xpath-starting-with) and [here](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element_by#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) with no luck.

The latest attempt in the snippet of my code looks like this:

```
menu_search_input_box_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, ‘txtMenuSearch_Namespace_’)]")
for item in menu_search_input_box_elements:
    print(item)
```

I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(@id, ‘txtMenuSearch_Namespace_’)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

In all my attempts to get the syntax right I keep getting this message.  Any help in figuring out how to `.send_keys()` to this field is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get en error because of the `‘’` quotes, replace them with correct ones.

```
# id starts with txtMenuSearch_Namespace_
menu_search_input_box_elements = driver.find_elements_css_selector("[id^='txtMenuSearch_Namespace_']")


menu_search_input_box_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'txtMenuSearch_Namespace_')]")
```

Comment: I'm seeing these invalid quotation characters popping up a lot here. I know my phone will type `‘’` characters when using iPhone / iOS, but I can fix that by pressing&holding the quotation character to force a 'normal' char. Are you aware of any other scenarios where these invalid quotations are typed out?

Comment: @Christine when using iOS I don't know how to use correct quotes besides copy paste. OP problems was because he copied from [here](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element_by#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath).